# SSH connection from A to B, then B connects to A

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh, rsync

I would like to connect in Rsync to a client that is already connected to my server via ssh.
Let's say I have client A connecting to client B via SSH, what I would like to do is establish an Rsync connection on computer A with computer B, but using the connection from A to B, without creating another one from B to A.
RSA keys are used for authentication on computer B.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want to run the rsync command on A or B (rsync can transfer in either direction of course)? Do you know how to use options like ControlMaster?

Comment: So far I've been trying to connect on A from B, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it yet. I would like to run the Rsync command on B to fetch files from A. I have no idea for now what the controlmaster option is.

Comment: Does it matter on which computer you execute rsync command? You can run `rsync B A` on A or B. Obviously, from B it will not work, as ssh does not, too. If you are connecting from A to B out of your network it is normal, that the connection works only one way. To connect from B to A you would need to allow a connection from outside to your network.

Comment: No actually it's the same, the connection from B to A was needed to run a bash script to fetch the data and update the data on a database, in this way I didn't want to run the main script on A, in the end I changed the approach and I run the script on A.